# Spectrum color picker: Prevent fake Cancel after Change event has fired

Tags: jquery, color-picker

I'm using the Spectrum color picker http://bgrins.github.com/spectrum. I like it a lot, but have one issue.

When I enter a color by text (in the color picker's input option) and press Enter, then the change event is fired, but the color picker is not closed. This means that the user can still click "Cancel", reverting the color picker to the original color. But in actuality it is too late - the deed is done!

I need to either close the color picker when Enter is pressed, or else not have it fire the Change event.

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2pub1j9w/

HTML

```
<input type='text' id="full"/>
```

JS

```
$("#full").spectrum({
    clickoutFiresChange: false,
    showInitial: true,
    showInput: true,
    preferredFormat: "hex",
     change: function(color) {
        alert("change");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably figured this out by now but you can use the change event for the change and the hide event for the cancel like this:

```
$("#textColor").spectrum({  
    showPalette: true,  
    color: calEvent.textColor,  
    palette: [  
        ['000000', 'FFFFFF', 'FFFF77'],  
        ['008000', 'C0C0C0', 'AE0000']  
    ],  
    change: function(color) {  
        $("#eventPreview").css( "color", color.toHexString() );  
    },  
    hide: function(color) {  
       $("#eventPreview").css( "color", color.toHexString() );  
    }  
});
```

The hide only is triggered from a cancel.